# How to create PlaneGeometry object at some height along z axis?

Tags: three.js

I am using this:

```
new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 1000, 1000 ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial() );
```

To create a new plane. How to change the height along z axis? None of the arguments are related to it.

Comment: First of all, in Three.js the X and Z axes are horizontal and the Y axis is vertical. Secondly, a plane is two-dimensional, so if you want a cube with height, you need to use THREE.CubeGeometry(width, height, depth). If what you actually want is a vertical plane, you need to rotate the plane: assign it to a variable like `geometry` instead of passing it directly to the mesh, then edit `geometry.rotation` to rotate it in the direction you want. (Units of rotation are in radians, so e.g. `geometry.rotation.z = Math.PI / 2` will rotate the plane 90 degrees.)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your mesh is captured as a variable like this:

```
var planeMesh = new THREE.Mesh( 
    new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 1000, 1000 ), 
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial() );
```

Then, all you need to do just to move it back is:

```
planeMesh.position.z += 50;
```

Also, [Icemonster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/843621/icemonster) is correct a plane will render facing you to start, thus depending on your use, you may want to rotate it as mentioned in the comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can rotate the mesh.  Try something like this:

```
mesh.rotation.set(-Math.PI/2, Math.PI/2000, Math.PI);
```